# Make QuillJS editor height 100%

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, quill

In the below application I want Quill editor to fill the existing space within header and footer. I tried making it 100% but that adds a scroll to the whole page. How to make Quill to fill the space at the same time to adapt screen size. (If the height is reduced editor height should be reduced)

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#editor-container {
  height: 100%;
}

#editor {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="editor-container">
    <div id="editor">Sample</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is `height: 100%` coming from the `ql-container` class which causes the overflow. You can try the below:

1. Add `flex: 1` to `#editor-container` and make it a *column flexbox* too.
2. Add `flex: 1` and `width: 100%` to `#editor` and for large content add `overflow-y: auto`

See demo below:

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#editor-container {
  height: 100%;
  /* added these styles */
  flex: 1;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

#editor {
  height: 100%;
  /* added these styles */
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="editor-container">
     <div id="editor">Sample</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is height: 100% coming from the ql-container class which causes the overflow. The same issue people are facing in react-quill

Just add the following css to your code it will overwrite quill style

```
    .ql-container {
  min-height: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ql-editor {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @prasun this answer helped a lot!!